# In PyQt, how does one get a shared menu and toolbar to talk to the currently active subwindow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an application which has a main window, which can have multiple subwindows. I would like to have one set of QActions in the main window that interact with the currently selected window. For example, the application might be a text editor, and clicking file->save should save the text file the user is currently working on. Additionally, some QActions are checkable, so their checked state should reflect the state of the currently active window.

Here is a minimum working example that has the basic functionality I want, but I suspect there is a better way to do it (further discussion below the code).

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui

class DisplayWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, name="Main Window"):
        # run the initializer of the class inherited from
        super(DisplayWindow, self).__init__()

        self.myLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()

        self.FooLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.FooLabel.setText(name)

        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.FooLabel)
        self.setLayout(self.myLayout)

        self.is_foo = False

    def toggle_foo(self):
        self.is_foo = not self.is_foo
        if self.is_foo:
            self.FooLabel.setText('foo')
        else: 
            self.FooLabel.setText('bar')

class WindowActionMain(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowActionMain, self).__init__()

        self.fooAction = QtGui.QAction('Foo', self) 
        self.fooAction.triggered.connect(self.set_foo)
        self.fooAction.setCheckable(True)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.fooAction)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('File')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.fooAction)

        self.centralZone = QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.centralZone.subWindowActivated.connect(
                               self.update_current_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralZone)
        self.create_dw("Window 1")
        self.create_dw("Window 2")

    def create_dw(self, name):
        dw = DisplayWindow(name=name)
        self.centralZone.addSubWindow(dw)
        dw.show()

    def update_current_window(self):
        """ redirect future actions to affect the newly selected window,
        and update checked statuses to reflect state of selected window"""

        current_window = self.centralZone.activeSubWindow()
        if current_window:
            self.current_dw = self.centralZone.activeSubWindow().widget()

        self.fooAction.setChecked(self.current_dw.is_foo)

    def set_foo(self):
        self.current_dw.toggle_foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WindowActionMain()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My actual version of DisplayWindow could be useful in many different projects, and I want to package it up so that you don't have to add a lot of code to the main window to use it. Therefore, DisplayWindow, all of its functionality and a list of available actions should be in one module, which would be imported in WindowActionMain's module. I should then be able to add more actions for DisplayWindow without changing any code in WindowActionMain. In particular, I don't want to have to write a little function like WindowActionMain.set_foo(self) just to redirect each action to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by handling the QMenu's aboutToShow signal
and considering the QGuiApplication's focusWindow (or however you get that in Qt4).
Example below shows a generic 'Window' menu acting on the frontmost window.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#aboutToShow
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#focusWindow

```
def on_windowMenu_aboutToShow(self):
    self.windowMenu.clear()
    self.newWindowAction = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
    self.newWindowAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+n")
    self.newWindowAction.triggered.connect(self.on_newWindowAction)
    self.newWindowAction.setText("New Window")
    self.windowMenu.addAction(self.newWindowAction)
    self.windowMenu.addSeparator()
    playerWindows = [w for w in self.topLevelWindows() if w.type()==QtCore.Qt.Window and w.isVisible()]
    for i, w in enumerate(playerWindows):
        def action(i,w):
            a = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
            a.setText("Show Window {num} - {title}".format(num=i+1, title=w.title()))
            a.triggered.connect(lambda : w.requestActivate())
            a.triggered.connect(lambda : w.raise_())
            self.windowMenu.addAction(a)
        action(i,w)
    self.windowMenu.addSeparator()
    self.closeWindowAction = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
    self.closeWindowAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+w")
    self.closeWindowAction.triggered.connect(lambda : self.focusWindow().close())
    self.closeWindowAction.setText("Close")
    self.windowMenu.addAction(self.closeWindowAction)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely interesting for the menu part of the question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `a.triggered.connect(lambda : w.requestActivate())` rather than `a.triggered.connect(w.requestActivate)`?

Comment: Overengineering; good spot, I've removed this from my own app now, thanks.